# Is HTTP Conditional GET reliable to detect if web contents has been modified?

Tags: http

I'd like to ask a question regarding HTTP Conditional GET. Is this actually reliable to detect changes of a web resource?

I mean, if I write a program to check if the page content is changed by using HTTP Conditional GET, is it possible that the web server is misconfigured (or intentionally configured) to return there are no changes even though the contents of the HTML or XML (Restful) has changed?

(I'm referring to requesting a web page with a header "If-Modified-Since" as part of the GET request. So, is the modified date that comes back is always reliable?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for a server to say that the content hasn't changed even though it has.  It is still just code running on the server so it can do anything it wants.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is possible. But the whole point of using a communication protocol, is that you trust that the other side is fulfilling it.

Usually, the situations like the one you mention are called "byzantine", because one of the ends is not following the protocol or failing, but cheating.